# NodeJs/NestJs which directory to install on Unix

Tags: node.js, linux, nestjs

Hi I have nodejs/nestjs microservice running in forever. I have installed in /home directory. I Have been reading around and home is not the correct place for this to be installed.

What is the correct directory to install it into? I is /srv or /usr/local or something else completely?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best directory for things like that is */opt*

You can read more about /opt and whole Filesystem Hierarchy here:

https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/opt.html

https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/index.html